# Read ULS Log Path Location from Central Administration

Tags: 2013, 2010, development, sharepoint-server, central-administration

I need to access ULS log path location from central administration through programmatically.

I used below code for get folder of logs and able to read all the logs text files.

```
  string logfolder = SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath("LOGS");
```

Above code is worked, I just changed Trace Log location to "C:\Logs" from Central Administration > Monitoring > Configure diagnostic logging.

Seem like all new ULS Logs append into `C:\Logs` new location so I would like to read this value from Central administration through Code Because GenericSetupPath always give us to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS`.

Please guild me if any suitable solution it would be big helpful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please look at this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spdiagnosticsservice.loglocation(v=office.15).aspx), it shows how to achieve what you're trying to do.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             SPDiagnosticsService diagSvc = SPDiagnosticsService.Local;
             string ulsLogLocation = diagSvc.LogLocation;
             Console.WriteLine(ulsLogLocation);

             Console.Write("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
             Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```